# Should I use Identity Server 4 for a single SPA client?

Tags: asp.net-core, jwt, frontend, single-page-application, identityserver4

I have been deeply studying everything I have been able to get my hands on regarding Identity Server 4. In an application I am working on the architecture of I will have an API and a React SPA.

In the past I would have just used JWT Authentication and called it a day, but I noticed that providing an SPA with a refresh token is a bad idea for security reasons. From my research I have been able to see that what fits my situation the best is to use Authorization Code Flow with PKCE enabled.

However, I don't have an SSO type of situation and I just want to have a single API, rather than an Authorization API and an application API, I am wondering if I should really use Identity Server at all. While Identity Server is powerful it seems rather overkill for my situation.

My only problem with my previous auth flow is the refresh token and keeping it secure. Is there a proper way to keep the refresh token secure in an SPA or is there another method I could use to mitigate the security flaw that is to store my refresh token in local storage or a cookie?

Comment: If you are not able to follow the specifications (OAuth2) and implement Identity Server with PKCE, then I think you are better not to use Identity Server, for the flow is the latest standard, and SPAs have a lot of security vulnerabilities if used with incorrect or customized flows.

Comment: I have a question regarding this, how bad would it be to make my application API also the authorization API? like I said, I don't have any other clients in mind other than my SPA, so making a full blown SSO seems like overkill.

Comment: Maybe this can help https://www.oauth.com/oauth2-servers/differences-between-oauth-1-2/separation-of-roles/. Separating is just a best practice, not a must.

Comment: Thanks! Much appreciated, navigating this topic has been very hard in general.

Comment: Yes it is really a big topic.